# How to properly debug why my Quartz.NET cron schedule is not trigger in .Net Core app

Tags: c#, .net-core, cron, quartz.net

I am using `Quartz` Jobs to make background data processing in my ASP Net Core project. I found that when i am using valid Cron Expressions they not triggered and there are no errors or warnings in logs / console.

My jobs configuration looks like:

```cs
 private void ConfigureRegularJobs(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddQuartz(quartz =>
     {
         quartz.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

         quartz.AddJob<SpectraIndexerJob>(job => job.WithIdentity(nameof(SpectraIndexerJob)));
         //todo: umv: move in config (every 3 hours)
         quartz.AddTrigger(trigger => trigger.ForJob(nameof(SpectraIndexerJob))                  .WithCronSchedule(_config.DefaultJobsSettings.DefaultSpectraIndexerSchedule));

              
         // other jobs ....

       });

       services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
}
```

My cron expressions are valid, they were generated using online generator: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

I.e. for upper mentioned job configuration i pass `"0/30 0 0 ? * * *"` as CRON-expression.

How to find reason of why my Jobs are not trigger?

Upd:

1. My Logs configuration is:

```json
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug",
      "Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler":  "Debug" 
    }
  },
```

2. If i replace `WithCronSchedule` with

```cs
.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                          .RepeatForever()));
```

everything works fine.

3. My logs from app including quartz logs:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[3]
      Hosting starting
dbug: Quartz.Simpl.TaskSchedulingThreadPool[0]
      TaskSchedulingThreadPool configured with max concurrency of 10 and TaskScheduler ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.
info: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl[0]
      Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]
      Quartz Scheduler created
info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]
      JobFactory set to: Quartz.Simpl.MicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory
info: Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore[0]
      RAMJobStore initialized.
info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]
      Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v3.4.0.0) 'Wissance.MossbauerLab.Watcher.ead4e265-d489-455e-b654-4ca7d9abc034' with instanceId 'ead4e265-d489-455e-b654-4ca7d9abc034'
  Scheduler class: 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0]
      Quartz scheduler 'Wissance.MossbauerLab.Watcher.ead4e265-d489-455e-b654-4ca7d9abc034' initialized
info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0]
      Quartz scheduler version: 3.4.0.0
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[2]
      Failed to locate the development https certificate at '(null)'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'https://localhost:5001/, http://localhost:5000/'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[4]
      Hosting started
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[0]
      Loaded hosting startup assembly Wissance.MossbauerLab.Watcher.Web
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\michael\Projects\Wissance\LabWatcher\Wissance.MossbauerLab.Watcher\Wissance.MossbauerLab.Watcher
Now listening on: http://localhost:7890
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]
      Scheduler Wissance.MossbauerLab.Watcher.ead4e265-d489-455e-b654-4ca7d9abc034_$_ead4e265-d489-455e-b654-4ca7d9abc034 started.
dbug: Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread[0]
      Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

Comment: The reason can almost always be found in logs. Just make sure you get the logging working and see output from Quartz. It should report what is happening and what the problem might be.

Comment: @MarkoLahma, thanks for reply, i've updated question and provided it with more info in particular with application logs

Comment: If you check your schedule on http://www.cronmaker.com/ you should see that it will fire on:

1. 2022-09-27 Tue 00:00:00
2. 2022-09-27 Tue 00:00:30
3. 2022-09-28 Wed 00:00:00
4. 2022-09-28 Wed 00:00:30
5. 2022-09-29 Thu 00:00:00

Are you checking around midnight?

Comment: I am looking for starting/stopping and passing parameters to jobs in my ASP Net Core application. Is it possible?

Comment: @Cenk, sure. Here you could find full example - https://github.com/Wissance/LabWatcher